# Twilio.Exceptions.ApiConnectionException: Connection Error. A task was cancelled - Twilio C#

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm facing an issue when fetching voice recordings for a specific date range. I could not reproduce the issue locally. 
But I continuously get the following error in production

"Twilio.Exceptions.ApiConnectionException: Connection Error: GEThttps://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountID/Recordings.json?DateCreated<=2018-10-27T06:27:49Z ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled."

The code we use is mentioned below. This code is run like every 2 minutes

```
string accountSid = string.Empty;
string authToken = string.Empty;

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAccountSID"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"]))
                    {
                        accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAccountSID"];
                        authToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"];

                        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
                        var deleteDateRange = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
                        var recordings = RecordingResource.Read(
                                              dateCreatedBefore: deleteDateRange
                                            );

                        if (recordings.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var recording in recordings)
                            {
                                RecordingResource.Delete(recording.Sid);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Are you using any Tasks or async methods?

Comment: Also, the if check before the foreach to delete can be removed, as the loop won't run if there are no elements anyway

Comment: Also in this case, `recordings.Any()` will be more efficient than `recordings.Count() > 0`, because count enumerates all elements.

Comment: I don't think so. (Not using tasks and Async methods)

Comment: Try changing `var recordings = RecordingResource.Read(dateCreatedBefore: deleteDateRange);` to `var recordings = RecordingResource.Read(dateCreatedBefore: deleteDateRange).ToList();` to force C# to fetch all the recordings before going into the loop.

Comment: Another thing you could try is use separate TwilioRestClients for the read and write operations. See this gist: https://gist.github.com/dprothero/20600365507f146b7b845e0e285efd5b

Comment: Let me know if either of those solves the issue for you and I'll post an "official" answer.

Comment: I dont think converting to .ToList() will make any difference as it has nothing to do with the exception I get. Will try this though. And will definitely try the second solution and lets see it makes any difference.

Comment: Reproduced the issue. Issue occurs when large number of requests are made to twilio simultaneously. Moved this method out of the thread to resolve this !